# Max height on Wordpress Video Widget

Tags: wordpress, video, widget, siteorigin

A video is inserted into a page using the "Video" widget in the SiteOrigin Page builder.
I seems like, when the video is renderen on the site, that it is set to fill the entire width of the site, using JavaScript.

I want the video to have a max height of 540px, but I can't seem to do it just using CSS.
I am also unable to locate the source file where the height is being set.

It looks like the widget is the "wp-widget-media-video" type.

Screenshot of the element in the inspector:
[image: The video element in the inspectr.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the size of the video is set using JS on load an resize, the solution was to set a max-width on the video, corresponding to the wished max height of the video. This was set on the .wp-video element using css.